# Nuget Build Triggers

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are considering a move to Azure DevOPS/TFS and we have built a prototype workflow which seems to work well.

The only outstanding thing from our current CI process to replicate is the triggering of builds based on nuget package updates.

Our build pipeline is a tree, where some libraries which generate nuget packages generated at the top of the tree are used as dependencies in other libraries downstream.

Using team city one of our build steps inspects the dependencies of a solution, identifies the topmost level dependencies and adds them as nuget build triggers ensuring that the next time a successful build of a dependency occurs the downstream library is triggered as well.

How can that be replicated in Azure Dev Ops?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after something like [NuKeeper](https://github.com/NuKeeperDotNet/NuKeeper):

> NuKeeper automates the routine task of discovering and applying NuGet
>   package updates.
>
> NuKeeper will compare the NuGet packages used in your solution to the
>   latest versions available on NuGet.org, and:
>
> - List available NuGet package updates on .NET code on the local file
>     system or on a GitHub server.
> - Apply NuGet package updates to .NET code
>     on the local file system.
> - Make pull requests containing updates to
>     code on a GitHub server.

[image: Process diagram]

<sub>Image stolen from [Shayne Boyer](http://tattoocoder.com/using-azuredevops-pipelines-and-nukeeper-to-automate-nuget-package-updates/)'s blog.</sub>